# Issues with SnapStore on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unity, 20.04, ubuntu-store

I upgraded to 20.04 and as the **Software Center** is removed from this release, I tried to open **SnapStore** but it wasn't opening at all. I removed it using

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
```

and reinstalled using

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
sudo snap install snap-store
```

After that, the snap store is opening now but it is displaying the window like this. There are boxes instead of alphabets and I am unable to do anything there as well. Is there anything I am doing wrong?
[image: snap store image]
Thanks
**Update 1**
I've installed the suggested packages but the snap store still shows the same writing style. I can now click on the visible icons but nothing is understandable.

```
jamshaid@jamshaid:~$ snap list
Name                Version                     Rev   Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core                16-2.44.3                   9066  latest/stable  canonical✓  core
core18              20200427                    1754  latest/stable  canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804     3.28.0-16-g27c9498.27c9498  116   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804     0+git.3009fc7               33    latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes   0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable  canonical✓  -
gtk2-common-themes  0.1                         9     latest/stable  canonical✓  -
snap-store          3.31.1+git187.84b64e0b      415   latest/stable  canonical✓  -
snapd               2.44.3                      7264  latest/stable  canonical✓  snapd
jamshaid@jamshaid:~$
```

Here's the new window of snap store
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By purging `snapd` you likely removed neccesary dependencies. Please run `snap list` in a terminal. You should see a list like this:

```
Name                     Version                     Rev   Aufzeichnung     Herausgeber       Hinweise
core                     16-2.44.3                   9066  latest/stable    canonical✓        core
core18                   20200427                    1754  latest/stable    canonical✓        base
gnome-3-28-1804          3.28.0-16-g27c9498.27c9498  116   latest/stable    canonical✓        -
gnome-3-34-1804          0+git.3009fc7               33    latest/stable/…  canonical✓        -
gtk-common-themes        0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable/…  canonical✓        -
gtk2-common-themes       0.1                         9     latest/stable    canonical✓        -
snap-store               3.36.0-74-ga164ec9          433   latest/stable/…  canonical✓        -
```

You're probably missing the core, gnome and gtk snaps. Reinstall them manually with `snap install <snap name>`.

In the future please don't purge snapd, that's pretty overkill.

Comment: I've installed these packages. Please have a look.

Comment: The fonts issue is resolved by refreshing the fonts cache, suggested in a comment above. the rest was corrected using your way.